# Duplicate class org.webrtc.AddIceObserver in flutter_webrtc and com.amazonaws:ivs-broadcast:1.9.0:stages@aar

Tags: android, flutter, amazon-ivs

I've encountered a problem with duplicate classes when using the flutter_webrtc and com.amazonaws:ivs-broadcast:1.9.0:stages@aar libraries together in my Flutter project.

In my pubspec.yaml I have:
flutter_webrtc: ^0.9.33

And in my build.gradle for Android, I have:
implementation('com.amazonaws:ivs-broadcast:1.9.0:stages@aar')

When I attempt to build, I encounter the following error:
Duplicate class org.webrtc.AddIceObserver found in modules jetified-android-104.5112.06-runtime (com.github.webrtc-sdk:android:104.5112.06) and jetified-ivs-broadcast-1.9-stages.0-stages-runtime (com.amazonaws:ivs-broadcast:1.9.0)

Could you please provide any guidance or potential solutions to address this issue?

I've tried to exclude the org.webrtc module from ivs-broadcast library in build.gradle, but the error persists.

`implementation('com.amazonaws:ivs-broadcast:1.9.0:stages@aar'){ exclude group: 'org.webrtc', module: 'webrtc' }`

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Are you using AWS IVS from a flutter app (as client)?